# how to concatenate a network path and combobox variable in powershell

Tags: combobox, powershell-3.0

please help. I have a the following function.

```
PROCESS {
    $ServersArray = @('localhost')
    foreach ($serverArray in $ServersArray) {
        try {
            if ($WebConfig.SelectedIndex -gt -1) {  
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Applying Maintenance on $ServerArray"
                $everything_ok = $true
                Invoke-Command  $serverArray -ScriptBlock { 
                    $filePath = "D:\\Inetpub\\MyHL3Ordering\\Configuration\\MyHL" + "\\" + $WebConfig.SelectedItem

                    (Get-Content $filePath) | ForEach-Object {
                        $_ -replace 'allowDO="true"','allowDO="false"'
                    } | Set-Content $filePath -Encoding UTF8; 
                }  -ErrorAction 'Stop'
            }
```

so basically I would like to concatenate the path with the combobox selected item. for example. if the selected item is web_da-DK.config , the path should be 
'D:\Inetpub\MyHL3Ordering\Configuration\MyHL\web_da-DK.config' but it is not working.

error is:

```
Cannot find part of the path 'D:\Inetpub\MyHL3Ordering\Configuration\MyHL\' it doesnt seem to concatenate the value of combobox selectedItem  to the path.
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please included the part of the scripts which creates and adds the combobox and also the parts of the scripts which cause the above code to be executed?

Comment: Just noticed that you're trying to access variables from a different scope when you are doing the `Invoke-Command` on a remote computer. I suggest reading up on scopes by running the command `Get-Help about_scopes`.

Comment: @robert.westerlund  i am trying the above code in powershell studio. if i run the command : 
Invoke-Command $serverArray -scriptblock { $filePath = "D:\Inetpub\MyHL3Ordering\Configuration\MyHL\Web_da-DK.config" (get-content $filePath) | foreach-object {$_ -replace 'allowDO="true"','allowDO="false"'} | set-content $filePath -Encoding UTF8; } -Credential $cred the above code works just fine but if i try to concatinate, it doesnt work. but if i try the concatenation outside the scriptblock, on debug i am able to see the entire concatinated path

Comment: If it works fine in the local scope, then it's highly likely that your problem is a scope issue. I have written an answer based on that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use a variable from a scope in which is does not exist. You can read more about scopes if you run the following command:

```
Get-Help about_scopes
```

Since you are using PowerShell v3 you can use the Using scope modifier. From the help on `about_scopes`:

> The Using scope modifier
>
> Using is a special scope modifier that identifies a local 
>      variable in a remote command. By default, variables in remote
>      commands are assumed to be defined in the remote session.
>
> The Using scope modifier is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.
>
> For more information, see about_Remote_Variables.

It further suggest reading the `about_Remote_Variables`, which states:

> USING LOCAL VARIABLES
>
> ```
> You can also use local variables in remote commands, but you must
> indicate that the variable is defined in the local session.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope
> modifier to identify a local variable in a remote command.
>
> The syntax of Using is as follows:
>
>    The syntax is:
>        $Using:<VariableName>
> ```

In order to take an example of this, we could make a sample first which tries to use the local variable immediately, like the following:

```
$serverArray = "localhost"
$filename = "somefile.txt"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerArray -ScriptBlock {
    $concatenated = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("C:\rootpath", $filename)
    Write-Host $concatenated
}
```

This will yield the following output:

```
C:\rootpath
```

If we change the script to use the Using scope modifier to indicate that we want to use a local variable from the remote scope, we get code like the following:

```
$serverArray = "localhost"
$filename = "somefile.txt"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerArray -ScriptBlock {
    $concatenated = [System.IO.Path]::Combine("C:\rootpath", $Using:filename)
    Write-Host $concatenated
}
```

This will yield the output which we want, that is:

```
C:\rootpath\somefile.txt
```

So what you need to do is to either pass it as an argument to the `Invoke-Command` function, using the `-ArgumentList` parameter, or (since you are using PowerShell v3) indicate that your variable is a local variable and use the Using scope modifier like the examples above.